# Extend SharePoint Client Object Model for SystemUpdate method

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

Is there a way to extend SharePoint client object model and add ListItem.SystemUpdate method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extend'? Are you just trying to update an item without changing its modified-by user/timestamp? You could host your own web service with an API to do this, though realistically you would have to pass in all the changes that you do want to make to the item...if you were truly determined you could probably reverse engineer the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client library so that you could grab the list of pending changes from the current ClientContext (and the necessary IDs to identify the list item), but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Agree with you. I mean update an item without changing its modified-by  user/timestamp. I too feel the only option is to host our own web service and call SystemUpdate method in service side. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Have you tried explicitly grabbing the current modified-by/modified properties and setting them before calling Update()? That works in some scenarios.

Comment: Yes it works. I just wanted to make it very simple with SystemUpdate. Otherwise we need to turn off/on document versioning, find userlookup values.. blob.. blob.. and call the update.

Comment: Vote for the feature here: http://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273492-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/10488873-add-listitem-systemupdate-method-to-the-sharepoi

Comment: The newer CSOM SDK has SystemUpdate() method available. https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The CSOM is not extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Finally SystemUpdate method is available in CSOM!!

CSOM package is 16.1.5626.1200

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated/